# Creating a batch/visual basic script to put a random quote into an html file

Tags: html, vbscript, batch-file, jscript

At work our end-users are on Windows XP and using Outlook Express. Whenever a user composes  an email or replies to one, Outlook Express "reads" a static html file located on c:\, and uses the content as a signature. This works perfectly fine.

Now my coworker gave me a simple text(.txt) file with 100+ lines, each line containing a "motivational quote".

My objective is to somehow have a random quote extracted from this text file, and inserted into the static html-signature file.

Since I am limited to what XP natively supports and can't install any additional software such as python, I assume either batch or vbscript would be the proper choice (if not only). I imagine a script which is executed via. the Windows Task Scheduler every 15 minutes or so, which randomly reads a line from the .txt-file, and updates it into the static html-signature file.

Is this possible in any way, or are neither batch nor vbscript capable of doing something like that?

Any help or advice will be GREATLY appreciated :)

Comment: Here's some jscript that solves a similar problem and wouldn't take much effort to adapt to the problem you describe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422231/how-to-create-a-c-c-program-that-generates-an-xml-and-runs-a-dos-command-after/8424376#8424376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a signature template that has embedded variables that are replaced by delayed expansion. Any exclamation point `!` or caret `^` literals must be encoded as variables as well:

`!QUOTE!` = The random quote
`!X!` = exclamation point literal
`!C!` = caret literal (probably not needed)

Additional variables could be added to the template as needed.

Here is a trivial HTML template as an example

```
<!X!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Random Quote</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><strong>!QUOTE!</strong></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The following batch file will select a random quote from the quote file and write out the signature file after replacing the variables in the template.

*EDIT - I improved performance and slightly altered the limitations by using FOR /F to read the quote line instead of SET /P.*

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

::Define the files
set quoteFile="quotes.txt"
set signatureTemplate="template.txt"
set signatureFile="signature.html"

::Define constants for ! and ^ substitutions in template
set "X=!"
set "C=^"

::Count the number of quotes
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<%quoteFile%') do set quoteCount=%%N

::Pick a random number of quotes to skip
set /a "skip=%random% %% %quoteCount%"

::Load the selected quote into a variable
if %skip% gtr 0 (set skip=skip=%skip%) else (set skip=)
for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%A in (%quoteFile%) do (
  set quote=%%A
  goto :break
)
:break

::Read the signature template and write the signature file
::Delayed expansion will automatically replace !quote!, !X! and !C!
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
>%signatureFile% (
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in (%signatureTemplate%) do echo %%A
)
```

There are a few limitations to the script as written:

- Template lines that are blank or begin with `;` will be skipped
- The quotes file must not have any blank lines or lines that start with `;`

Comment: Clever!  The template approach was my first thought but I never knew how to do that with a batch file.  Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a batch script that will get a random line from a file in one pass and then print it to the console and write it to a file.

So where I have `echo !LINE!` is where you'd write your HTML file.  It's actually kind of painful in batch because `>`, `<`, `%`, `^`, `!`, and others characters are special and need to be escaped with `^` in front.

```
@echo off
SET /A LINE_NUM=0
SET LINE=

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%l in (random_lines.txt) do (
        call:rand 0 !LINE_NUM!
        IF !RAND_NUM! LSS 1 (
                SET LINE=%%l
        )
        SET /A LINE_NUM=!LINE_NUM! + 1
)

echo !LINE!
echo ^<^^!doctype html^>^<html^>^<head^>^<title^>Random Quote^</title^>^</head^>
 > %OUT_FILE%
echo ^<body^>^<p^>^<strong^>!LINE!^</strong^>^</p^> >> %OUT_FILE%
echo ^</body^>^</html^> >> %OUT_FILE%

goto :EOF

REM rand()
REM Input: %1 is min, %2 is max
REM Output: RAND_NUM is set to a random number from min through max.
:rand
SET /A RAND_NUM=%RANDOM% * (%2 - %1 + 1) / 32768 + %1
goto :EOF
```

Alternatively, and probably better, instead of putting the HTML inside the batch file, you can keep it in a separate file in two pieces.  The glue that joins the two pieces and makes a complete HTML file is the line you picked.  For example, I can create a file called `sig_file_header.txt` that contains this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Random Quote</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p><strong>
```

Then I can create a file called `sig_file_footer.txt` with this:

```
    </strong></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice that when I put these files together, header followed by footer, I get a full HTML document.  So when I put them together, I can cram the line the script picked in there and get a full HTML document with the line in it.

Doing that is easy.  Replace the 4 lines starting with `echo !LINE!` in the script above with the following 3:

```
type sig_file_header.txt > new_signature_file.html
echo !LINE! >> new_signature_file.html
type sig_file_footer.txt >> new_signature_file.html
```

Comment: This seems like it could potentially be EXACTLY what I need! Awesome! Although I'm a bit unsure what you mean by re-writing my signature file. The signature file is a static html file which can't include anything fancy such as php or Outlook Express will just ignore it. How do you suggest I inject the contents of random_lines.txt into my signature.html file?

Comment: I updated my code to write an HTML file.  Batch isn't fun for that because you have to litter the markup with `^` so that the batch file doesn't try to evaluate the character that follows.  I'm not sure there's an easy solution to writing the line to your HTML file in batch.  Simple search and replace isn't so simple in a batch file...

Comment: OK, an easier way to do the HTML is just to split the HTML file into 2 pieces manually and put them back together with the batch file.  When putting the files back together, the batch file conveniently inserts the line it picked.  I updated the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: @Paul:  And by "re-write", I mean "overwrite".  Overwrite the old signature file with the new one your batch file creates.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to

1. Get the count of lines in the file.
2. Get a random number n between 1 and the number of lines.
3. Get the nth line from the file.

That should be reasonably simple to accomplish with a batch script. Unfortunately, I don't know any Windows batch script, so I can't provide any more advice.